# WCF over HTTPS in Monotouch?

Tags: wcf, https, xamarin.ios

I am trying to call a wcf service over https and have followed the suggested setup from [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_Web_Services#Consuming_WCF_Services).  It works fine over http, but I get a RemoteCertificateNameMismatch error over https which I am handling with this (as suggested) -

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
          (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { return true; };
```

I later get a 415 unsupported media type error which I can't figure out. I have a win .net test client that is able to call the service and receive results, but from monotouch I can't get it to work.  Has anyone been able to do this successfully and wouldn't mind pasting an example?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

HTTP error codes comes from the server side. Of course the client configuration may play a role into this.

If possible switch to HTTP and compare sessions (e.g. using `wireshark`) between your Windows's and MonoTouch clients. Doing so in HTTPS may tell you a *few* things but that's less  likely to be helpful.

Also check for [similars](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/01/wcf-webhttp-service-returns-http-415-unsupported-media-type.aspx) `415` errors affecting other (non-MonoTouch) projects. Since the error comes the server the information they provide might help you find what's going on.